# DropDownList MVC C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdownlist, but am struggling with how I display it.

I have the following code.

**Controller**

```
            var trader = new DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel
            {
                Description = data.Description,
                Id = data.Id,
                BusinessName = traders.Select(x => new BusinessNameViewModel { BusinessName = x.BusinessName, Id = x.Id }),
                Categories = _service.GetCategories().Select(x => new DropDownViewModel {Id = x.Id, Description = x.Description }).OrderBy(x=>x.Description)
            };
```

**DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel**

```
public class DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [UIHint("BusinessNameDisplayTemplate")]
    public IEnumerable<BusinessNameViewModel> BusinessName { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DropDownEditorTemplate")]
    public IEnumerable<DropDownViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**DropDownViewModel**

```
public class DropDownViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**DropDownEditorTemplate**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Internal.ViewModels.Controller.DropDownViewModel>>" %>
<table class="aligncenter">
  <tr class="tRow left"><%
    if (Model != null)
    {%>
      <td>
        <%=Html.DropDownList("Category", Model.)%> 
      </td><%
    }%>                        
  </tr>
</table>
```

I dont know what I'm meant to provide within the DropDownList or if I'm actually doing it correct.

**UPDATE**

**Controller**

```
            var trader = new DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel
            {
                Description = data.Description,
                Id = data.Id,
                BusinessName = traders.Select(x => new BusinessNameViewModel { BusinessName = x.BusinessName, Id = x.Id }),
                Categories = _service.GetCategories().Select(x => new SelectListItem() {Text = x.Description, Value = x.Id.ToString(), Selected = true})
            };
```

**DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [UIHint("BusinessNameDisplayTemplate")]
    public IEnumerable<BusinessNameViewModel> BusinessName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

    public int Category { get; set; }

    public string Button { get; set; }
```

**DeleteCategoryAttachedToTraders.aspx**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteCategoryFromTradersAttachNewCategory", "Controller",FormMethod.Post))
    <%=Html.DropDownList("Categories")%>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult DeleteCategoryFromTradersAttachNewCategory(DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel displayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel)
            {
                if (displayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel.Button == "Back to List") return RedirectToAction("ViewCategories");

            //Update traders with new category
            //delete category

            //if (_service.DeleteCategory((int)deleteCategoryViewModel.Id))
            //{
            //    return RedirectToAction("ViewCategories");
            //}

            return View("DeleteCategoryAttachedToTraders", displayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel);
        }
```

When I access the controller via the Submit button nothing is stored within the DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ŁukaszW.pl / ajay_whiz for your help :-) In the end I used a mixture of both answers:

**Controller**

```
Categories = _service.GetCategories(id).Select(x => new SelectListItem {Text = x.Description, Value = x.Id.ToString()})
```

**DisplayTradersAttachedToCategoryViewModel**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
```

**DeleteCategoryAttachedToTraders.aspx**

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Category", Model.Categories)%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Tameside.Internal.ViewModels.BuyWithConfidence.DropDownViewModel>>" %>
 <select>
     <% foreach(var category in Model.Categories) { %>
         <option value="<%= Html.Encode(category.Id) %>"><%= Html.Encode(category.Name %></option>
     <% } %>
 </select>
```

ofcourse Id and Name are just members out of my head. Use those which are in your category class.

Comment: How do I name the select list? At the moment the value is not being returned via the view model.

Comment: Just put the 'name' attribute to the select tag

Comment: It's still a good idea to mark my post as answer.. Thanks in advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try casting it to `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)` i.e.

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Category", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Categories)%>
```

**-or-**

create a model property of type **SelectList**
and you can initialize it as

```
new SelectList(Categories.ToList(), "ID", "Description");
```

Comment: This cast will not work.. how can it cast Category to SelectListItem?

Also... You give a whole object as a parameter to DropDownList helper and in my opinion it cannot recognize what should be display and what should be value member in html code that it generates.

Comment: try it out and see... also i had given alternate to it... instead of writing for each statement you can do it with SelectList

Comment: Hello ajay_whiz, I am trying it your way but can you have a look at my post again as the data isn't getting passed through the viewmodel